# How to assign the FC result to a variable (Batch File)

Tags: batch-file

May I know how can I assign the result of the "FC" command to a variable

Here's my script:

```
for /f %%i in ('FC /b "C:\MD5Checksum\ChecksumFromActualVM\* C:\MD5Checksum\ChecksumFromRestoredVM\*') do set result=%%i
```

but if I echo the result, I only get this output "FC:"

Comment: if you don't need the literal result and only want to know if the files are equal, you can use the errorlevel or conditional executing (no `for` loop needed) ([example](https://ss64.com/nt/fc.html))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that there are no assignment of items split by specific delimiters:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('FC /b "C:\MD5Checksum\ChecksumFromActualVM\*" "C:\MD5Checksum\ChecksumFromRestoredVM\*"') do set "result=%%~i"
```

Assuming you are aware that this will only return the last line that specifies that there are/are not differences.